# T-sql script to replace first 2 numbers in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Table `Parameter` contains column `SerialNumber`. The value `SerialNumber` is prefixed with the number 99. Sample: `99064960`.

```
Table.Parameter
-------------
[ParameterID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[SerialNumber] [varchar](10) NULL,
```

I would like to script a change to replace 99 with 88 on all rows.

Expected result: `88064960`.

Using the following statement the issue was resolved but question was posted to amalgamate these functions into a single statement.

```
UPDATE table
SET SerialNumber = SUBSTRING(SerialNumber, 3, LEN(SerialNumber)-2)
WHERE ID IN ( )
```

This string then added the prefix:

```
update table
set SerialNumber = '88' + SerialNumber 
where ID in ( )
```

Thank you.

Comment: Questions will too much *irrelevant* text get downvoted. There's no such thing as too many details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET field = '88' + SUBSTRING(field, 3)
WHERE SUBSTRING(field, 1, 2) = '99'
```

Comment: Thanks, helped , following executed successfully.

UPDATE table 
SET SerialNumber = SUBSTRING(SerialNumber, 3, LEN(SerialNumber)-2)
WHERE ID IN ()

update table
set SerialNumber = 'FA' + SerialNumber
WHERE ID IN ()

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(100)
SET @str='99064960'
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN LEFT(@str,2)='99'
        THEN '88'+SUBSTRING(@str,3,LEN(@str))
        ELSE @str
    END
```

In a update statement like this:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET theString='88'+SUBSTRING(@str,3,LEN(@str))
WHERE LEFT(Table1.theString,2)='99'
```

Reference:

- [LEFT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx)
- [SUBSTRING (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx)